# create a cube 3D with a curve inside it using xyz using asp.net or mvc

Tags: asp.net

Create a cube 3D with a curve inside it using xyz in asp.net or mvc
create a rotatable curve inside 3d cube with dummy values

Comment: So, where is your code or at least your attempt?

Comment: That sounds like homework and/or a poorly specified project. What's your specific question? Which bit particular can't you get to work?